# iOS - Open Microsoft tag reader from link in web app

Tags: ios, tags, microsoft-tag

We are building a web app that uses QR codes and redirects. We are also using Microsoft Tag to read QR codes. We would like a link within our web app that opens up the tag reader. I have been searching everything and the closest I have come is a link here about android...but this is iOS.

Does anyone know the syntax to open a native app? I have seen other sites do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the URL scheme of the Microsoft Tag application. I don't know where, or if, you can get it.

If you happen to find it, you can open the application with something like this:

```
 <a href="applicationurlscheme:">Open the Microsoft Tag application</a>;
```

Or in Objective-C:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"applicationurlscheme:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

See [this](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes), [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/) and [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) for more information.